# How to identify nth lines of n files in while<>

Tags: perl, vector, sum, filehandle

I have a code which adds all vectors in all files. 
There can be any number of input files. For example first input file is:

```
0.55        0       0.3335      1.2
0.212       0       2.2025      1
```

and the second one is:

```
0.25        0       0.3333      1.0
0.1235      0       0.2454      1
```

What I get is the sum of all vectors, thus in result i get one vector
which is:

```
1.13550     0       3.1147      4.2
```

But I'm trying to sum the first vector of the first file with the first vector of the second file and so on. In result according to this example I should get 2 vectors.

For now I have this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if ($ARGV[0] ne "vector1.dat"){
    die ("vector1.dat is necessary as first argument");
}

my @sum = 0;
my $dim = 0;

while (<>) {

    #Ignore blank lines, hashtags 
    #and lines starting with $
    if ($_ =~ /#/ || $_ =~ /^$/ || $_ =~ /^\s$/){
        next;
    }
    my @vectors = split(" ", $_);
    my $vector_length = @vectors;

    if ($dim eq 0) {
        $dim = $vector_length;
    } 
    else {
        if ($dim ne $vector_length) {
            die ("Vector dimensions do not match. : $!");
        }
    }
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#vectors; $i++) {
        $sum[$i] += $vectors[$i];
    }
}

$" = "\t\t";
print "\n --- \n @sum \n";
```

What I need is just to find out how to identify each file's nth line
and to sum the column values of those lines while keeping in mind, that there can be n number of files. 
I saw filehandling question over here with similar issue, however 
I didn't find my answer there.
Just looking for some suggestions and guidance. Got stuck on this.

Comment: You should `use warnings 'all'` in preference to `-w` on the shebang line. Don't use both

Comment: `my @sum = 0`? What is that supposed to mean? An array where the first element is 0?

Comment: If you intended `/^$/` to check for lines starting with dollar sign `$`, that will not work, as `$` is a regex meta character. Which you incidentally show in the next regex.

Comment: @briandfoy No, that would be the third regex looking for blank lines. `/^\s$/`. He says in the comments that it is "lines starting with $".

Comment: Thank you for the advice about shebang, I will keep that in mind.
About @sum- good point, it's absolutely not necessary.
I will keep in mind that there are better ways for finding blank lines, thank you for that notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open each file yourself and use the `$.` variable to know which line you are on (or count the files yourself). Here's the basic structure:

```
foreach my $file ( @files ) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die ...;
    while( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        $sum[ $. ] = ...;  # $. is the line number
        }
    }
```

If you don't like `$.`, you can use its longer name. You have to turn on [English](http://www.metacpan.org/modules/English)  (which comes with Perl):

```
use English;
## use English qw( -no_match_vars );  # for v5.16 and earlier

foreach my $file ( @files ) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die ...;
    while( <$fh> ) {
        chomp;
        $sum[ $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER ] = ...;
        }
    }
```

Or, you can count yourself, which might be handy if the vectors in the files don't line up by strict line number (perhaps because of comments or some other formatting oddity):

```
foreach my $file ( @files ) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die ...;
    my $line = -1;
    while( <$fh> ) {
        $line++;
        chomp;
        $sum[ $line ] = ...;
        }
    }
```

The harder way is [the answer bart gives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35973278/2766176) which inspects [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) at the end of every line to see if the magical ARGV handle is looking at a new file, and resetting `$.` if it is. It's an interesting trick but hardly anyone is going to understand what it's doing (or even notice it).

For the other part of the problem, I think you're doing the vector sum wrong, or using confusing variable names. A line is a vector, and the numbers in the lines are a component. A two dimensional array will work. The first index is the line number and the second in the component index:

```
while( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    ... skip unwanted lines
    my @components = split;
    ... various dimension checks
    foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#components ) {
        $sum[ $. ][ $i ] += $components[ $i ];
        }
    }
```

The [Data::Dumper](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper) module is handy for complex data structures. You can also see the [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) (Perl Data Structures Cookbook) documentation. The `$.` variable is found in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: Thank you, your explanations helped me a lot.
Totally didn't think about a two dimensional array, that's
a good notice.

Comment: Don't need to `chomp($_)` if `$_` is only used in `split(' ', $_)`.

Comment: Re "but hardly anyone is going to understand", That's what comments are for.

Comment: If you really did want to avoid magic, you'd use `my $input_line_number = $.;` instead of `use English;`

Answer (score 0):

`$.` is the line number of the most recently read file handle. `close(ARGV) if eof;` can be used to reset the file number between files (as documented in [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html)). (Note: `eof()` is different than `eof`.) So you now have line numbers.

The second problem you have is that you are adding vector components (`$vectors[$i]`) to a vectors (`$sum[$i]`). You need to add vector components to vectors components. Start by using more appropriate variable names.

This is what we get:

```
my @sum_vectors;
while (<>) {
   s/#.*//;          # Remove comments.
   next if /^\s*$/;  # Ignore blank lines.

   my @vector = split;

   if ($sum_vectors[$.] && @{ $sum_vectors[$.] } != @vector) {
      die("$ARGV:$.: Vector dimensions do not match\n");
   }

   for my $i (0..$#vector) {
      $sum_vectors[$.][$i] += $vector[$i];
   }
} continue {
   close(ARGV) if eof;  # Reset line numbers for each file.
}
```

Two other errors fixed:

- `$!` did not contain anything meaningful when you used it.
- You ignored lines that contain comments, even if they contained valid data too.

Comment: I will be more specific when declaring variables, sorry for confusing readers with inappropriate names.

Comment: That's not it. It's important to choose appropriate names to avoid confusing *oneself*. With the names I used, your incorrect addition (`$sum_vectors[$i] += $vector[$i];`) would have looked incorrect. You would have been able to tell something's wrong by yourself.

Comment: That's true. Will be careful with namings. And yes, I already noticed the useless $! variable too. As for comments, that's a really good point. Thank you for your help you made me notice really simple but important things that I missed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

if ($ARGV[0] ne "vector1.dat"){
    die ("vector1.dat is necessary as first argument");
}

my %sum;
my $dim = 0;
my $vector_length;
my $line_number;

while (<>) {

    #Ignore blank lines, hashtags
    #and lines starting with $
    if ($_ =~ /#/ || $_ =~ /^$/ || $_ =~ /^\s$/){
        next;
    }
    my @vectors = split(" ", $_);
    $vector_length = @vectors;

    if ($dim eq 0) {
        $dim = $vector_length;
    }
    else {
        if ($dim ne $vector_length) {
            die ("Vector dimensions do not match. : $!");
        }
    }
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#vectors; $i++) {
        $sum{$.}{$i} += $vectors[$i];
    }
    $line_number = $.;
    $. = 0 if eof;
}

$" = "\t\t";
for (my $line=1; $line<=$line_number; $line++)
{
    print $line;
    for (my $vector=0; $vector<$vector_length; $vector++)
    {
        print " " . $sum{$line}{$vector};
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: "Try this" answers without further explanations are rather annoying, and not very valuable. It means I have to read through your entire code, see how it is different from the OPs, and try to discern what you are trying to do, and if you did it right.

Comment: `close(ARGV) if eof;` is the documented example.

Comment: That doesn't work if the last line is blank or a comment.